# Creating and adding items to a Linked List stored in an object

Tags: java, list, class, linked-list

I have a files of zipcode, cities, and states.  I need to create a class to store these items.  The objects will be stored in a binary search tree so I need only one entry per city, state combination.  Since some cities have multiple zipcodes, I have been asked to store the zip codes in a list within the class.

basic structure:

```
public class Places(String city, String state, String zip){
  . . . 
}
```

I believe I need to create the LinkedList within the class and then add the zip too it, but when I do so I am getting a null pointer exception.

```
//create new LinkedList in Place
      LinkedList<String> zips = new LinkedList<String>();
      zips.add(zip);
```

I have found plenty of information about adding objects to lists, but not using lists within objects.

Comment: Needs more code!  I can't see how the above code causes a `NullPointerException`.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: The code snippet you show should _not_ be causing a `NullPointerException`.  You must be doing something else.

Comment: Could it be that `zip` is null? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @dave that won't raise a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza okay - `add()` *can* raise a `NullPointerException`. I take it `ArrayList` allows `null` elements so it won't in this case.

Comment: @dave nope, it won't. It will assign `null` as data to the node and continue working with no problem. `List#add` using JDK implementations of `List` won't raise a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to contain a [mcve].  Without it, we can only guess what's really going on.  (As a bonus, the effort itself might lead you to an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 public class LocationData{
     //Somewhere in your code initiate it, maybe in constructor?
     public LinkedList<String> zips=new LinkedList<String>();
     //do the rest of what this class needs to do
  }
```

In another class that uses `LocationData`:

```
  public class TestClass {
      //or any other method for that matter
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         LocationData ld=new LocationData();
         ld.zips.add("12345"); //adds zipcode of "12345"
        }
   }
```

The only way a `NullPointerException` could be raised is if `ld` or `zips` is uninitialized. I can't tell exactly where your exception is being raised since you didn't post a complete section of your code.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.  So, there were zips in the file with a null value so the linked list was throwing a null pointer exception.  I changed it to an array list and it worked fine.

Thanks,
Jen